# Strange behaviour with envsubst command

Tags: bash, shell, return-code

I try to check the command return inside my bash script for all commands. I created a function for this named *check_command_return_code*. This function is called in some other function which run command and it seems to work as expected except for the envsubst command.

This is my *check_command_return_code*:

```
check_command_return_code(){
  "$@"
  if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "[ERROR] Error with command $@"
    exit 1
  fi
  echo "[SUCCESS] Command $@ has successfully run"
}
```

I also write this function in order to substitute env variable inside yaml file:

```
substitute_env_variables_into_file(){
  echo "Create new file named $2 from $1 by substituting environment variables within it"
  check_command_return_code envsubst < $1 > $2

}
```

I call my function which proceeds the substitution like this:

```
substitute_env_variables_into_file "./ingress-values.yaml" "./ingress-values-subst.yaml"
```

This is my *ingress-values.yaml* file:

```
controller:
  replicaCount: 2
  service:
    loadBalancerIP: "$INTERNAL_LOAD_BALANCER_IP"
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

I expect my *ingress-values-subst.yaml* looks like this:

```
controller:
  replicaCount: 2
  service:
    loadBalancerIP: "my_private_ip"
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal:
```

Unfortunately the *ingress-values-subst.yaml* is expanded with the echo of my *check_command_return_code* function as you can see:

```
controller:
  replicaCount: 2
  service:
    loadBalancerIP: "my_private_ip"
    annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
[SUCCESS] Command envsubst has successfully run
```

I enabled the "debug" mode thanks to the following command in order to have more verbosity:

```
set -x
```

These logs are those from the output of my script:

```
++ substitute_env_variables_into_file ./private-ingress-values.yaml ./private-ingress-values-subst.yaml
++ echo 'Create new file named ./ingress/private-ingress-values-subst.yaml from ./private-ingress-values.yaml by substituting environment variables within it'
Create new file named ./private-ingress-values-subst.yaml from ./private-ingress-values.yaml by substituting environment variables within it
++ check_command_return_code envsubst
++ envsubst
++ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
++ echo '[SUCCESS] Command envsubst has successfully run'
```

I don't understand why the parameter of my command envsubst are not passed into my *check_command_return_code* function as you can see in the previous logs.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `echo "[ERROR] Error with command $@"` really feels like an error message.  As such, it belongs on stderr: `echo "[ERROR] Error with command $@" >&2`

Comment: Thank you @WilliamPursell but why do you not use $* in your echo command instead of $@? I know when the both params are quoted "$*" takes all the params into the first one whereas "$@" can correctly parse and affect them to the right positions. In your command example, can I use the both notations?

Comment: I used `$@` simply because I cut-n-pasted from the question.  Using`$@` in double quotes where it is not the only thing in the double quotes is generally not a good idea.  Most(?) shells will expand `"foo $@"` the same as `"foo" "$1" "$2" ...`, but I believe the behavior is not fully specified in any standard.  In this case `$*` would do fine, but personally I would just use `$1` here, or nothing at all. (The error message from the command itself should be sufficient.). My remark was really focused on the redirect to stderr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why the parameter of my command envsubst are not passed into my check_command_return_code

Redirections are not parameters. Redirections are opened at the time the line is executed.

When you do `your_function > file`, then inside `your_function` standard output is redirected to `file` for the whole duration of the function, including all the commands inside `your_function`.

Wrap it in yet another function:

```
myenvsubst() {
    envsubst < "$1" > "$2"
}
check_command_return_code myenvsubst "$1" "$2"
```

Or better yet, write log information to standard error, or another file descriptor.

```
    echo "[ERROR] Error with command $*" >&2
```

---

Check your scripts with shellcheck to find such problems like:

> ```
> < $1 > $2
> ```

are not quoted. They should be `< "$1" > "$2"`

> ```
> if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
> ```

is an antipattern. Prefer `if ! "$@"; then`.

> ```
> echo "[ERROR] Error with command $@"
> ```

is an odd usage of quoted `$@`. Prefer `$*`, or move to a separate argument.

Comment: Thanks you very much @KamilCuk for you help.  I create a new function as you advise me and it works. If I correctly understand I don't need to show an error message if I use set -e ? One of your advice is to use if ! "$@"; then so I deduce in case of error this is handled by set -e. Am I right?
What is the best practice between the use of "$@" in the previous if statement and"$*" please? I tested the both and in my logs the entire envsubst (with file parameters) command does not appear. Only envsubst does.

Comment: `I don't need to show an error message if I use set -e ?` That's unrelated, set -e exits the script in specific situations, it does not _show_ any message if it exists. `then so I deduce in case of error this is handled by set -e` No, it's handled by `if`. `if ! "$@"; then`. `What is the best practice between the use of "$@" in the previous if statement and"$*" please?` Check your script with shellcheck. Shellcheck explains the difference in documentation of error codes.